# Returning aggregate value on lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aggregateresult

I am trying to create a lightning component to display a single number which is the sum or count of a power of 1 field.
Found solutions to display a list of aggregate but not an unique number. Below my codes that do not work. The page displays but not the aggregate sum. Any idea?

APEX

```
public class RenewalsAPEXController {

@AuraEnabled        
public static AggregateResult getRenewals(){      

    return [SELECT SUM(OpportunitiesCount__c) renewals FROM Opportunity WHERE ((RecordTypeId = '012280000005zPW') and (StageName != 'Closed Won' or StageName != 'Closed Lost') and (OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()))];
}      
}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="RenewalsAPEXController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="renewals" type="integer"/>    
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->  
<article class="slds-card">
    <header class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
      ...
    </header>   
    <div class="slds-card__body">           
        <ui:outputNumber value="{!v.renewals}" />  
    </div>     
</article>        
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
doInit: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getRenewals");

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.renewals", a.getReturnValue());            
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Sylvie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer type in your return type in apex , the apex controller can be modified as below .The aggregate object might not be supported as return type

```
@AuraEnabled        
public static Integer getRenewals(){      

   AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(OpportunitiesCount__c)renewals FROM Opportunity WHERE ((RecordTypeId = '012280000005zPW') and (StageName != 'Closed Won' or StageName != 'Closed Lost') and (OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()))];
   Integer sum = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('renewals');
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohith for your quick response, but it is still not displaying anything.

Comment: can you put a console log for a.getReturnValue() and see what value you get .

Comment: Also turn on the debug logs in apex and see if the value in logs is fine

Comment: I found the problem. I have to changed Integer by Decimal as a type and it works. Thank you so much for your guidance.